# Push to Heroku hanging after ative_admin fetch

Tags: heroku, activeadmin

Guys I have no clue why this push to Heroku isn't working. Any ideas?

```
Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
   fatal: Could not parse object '54fb71c5415f7b1a7aa0cdde680ee882fa3b2d6f'.
   Git error: command `git reset --hard 54fb71c5415f7b1a7aa0cdde680ee882fa3b2d6f`
   in directory
   /tmp/build_1660sx0l4npgk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-54fb71c5415f
   has failed.
   If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
   '/tmp/build_1660sx0l4npgk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca'
   Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Fetching git://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic.git
   Fetching git://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources.git
   Fetching git://github.com/ernie/ransack.git
   Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
   fatal: Could not parse object '54fb71c5415f7b1a7aa0cdde680ee882fa3b2d6f'.
   Git error: command `git reset --hard 54fb71c5415f7b1a7aa0cdde680ee882fa3b2d6f`
   in directory
   /tmp/build_1660sx0l4npgk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-54fb71c5415f
   has failed.
   If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
   '/tmp/build_1660sx0l4npgk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca'
```

!
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

Comment: I don't see that commit ID in the master branch of the Github project (active_admin). In your Gemfile, are you simply adding active_admin like any other gem (i.e. gem 'active_admin')? Please post the lines pertaining to active_admin in your Gemfile.lock file.

Comment: Solved it. I deleted the Gemfile.lock and ran bundle install.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error today and found that my Gemfile.lock file included a reference to the same commit you were using:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
  revision: 54fb71c5415f7b1a7aa0cdde680ee882fa3b2d6f
  branch: rails4
  specs:
    activeadmin (0.6.0)
    ...
```

I'm not sure why that commit is [no longer available](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commits/rails4) but I was able to specify one in my Gemfile using the :ref option:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4', ref: 'a9949c1524205928b18597f840e83478ba97c2ef'
```

The resulting change to Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
 remote: git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
 revision: a9949c1524205928b18597f840e83478ba97c2ef
 ref: a9949c1524205928b18597f840e83478ba97c2ef
 branch: rails4
 specs:
   activeadmin (0.6.0)
   ...
```

This feels like a safer way to control when including libraries directly from Github.